# Seeking a story about intelligent microscopic beings living on either Jupiter or Saturn. One of the beings is curious and wants to space travel

Tags: story-identification, novel

Intelligent Protozoa living on Jupiter or Saturn. One is curious about the universe and wants to space travel.  It eventually does get off the planet, but smashes against the window of a space ship.  It dies knowing that it has found life outside its own world.

Comment: A couple of famous stories about "intelligent microscopic beings" are "Surface Tension" by James Blish and *Dragon's Egg* by Robert L. Forward, but neither of those matches your description so we can rule them out. About how old is the story you're looking for? When did you read it?

Comment: @user14111, I think I read it in the early 80’s.  I was very much into fantasy and sci fi at that time.  I had subscriptions to Analog and Omni, and read any novel I could get my hands on.  I remember this as a short novel.  I also remember that it was very technical, very science based and a little hard to read for that reason.  The character of the microscopic being was so wonderful- I have always wanted to find the story again.